# Is there a pexpect like automation for serial-term or term-mode

Tags: python, term, automation

Is there something similar to pexpect that can be used to automate a tty connection running inside emacs, i.e. in term-mode or on top of `serial-term` ? I'd like to automate some repetitive tasks like firmware flashing from within emacs.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "similar to pexpect". Questions should pretty much stand on their own.

Comment: @Drew : pexpect is a python script that can be used to automate a sequence of tasks controlled via input/output channel like a port, i.e. If you want to run uboot via tty you can first query the state (i.e. try ping etc) and react accordingly, like start tftp if server can be reached, it is also used for i.e. ssh session automation etc.

Comment: Please put all such info in the question. Comments can be deleted at any time. Questions need to stand on their own.

Comment: @Drew : If you dont know what pexpect is then you probably dont know an answer anyway.

Comment: You're not getting it. It's not about me. It's about having questions and answers that help people generally (and not just the question poser).